# zsh command not found cloud_sql_proxy

Tags: cloud-sql-proxy

I'm trying to connect to the Google Cloud SQL through local proxy. When I try to use cloud_sql_proxy in the Terminal on Mac, it says zsh command not found cloud_sql_proxy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I try to connect to the cloud_sql_proxy, I used `cloud_sql_proxy` instead of `./cloud_sql_proxy`